# Qt 3D QML Geometry Renderer

Tags: qml, qt3d

I'm trying to use QML GeometryRenderer to draw my own 3D geometry but something goes wrong. I added other 3D elements to check if they are displayed and this happens. have someone any suggestions? I think that the problem comes with geometry definition. when I change my own geometry with a well-known SphereGeometry inside GeometryRenderer the sphere is correctly shown. I cannot find a complete documentation on the Qt website or even a simple example to test and to use as a starting project.

here is the following my code:

**GeometryRender.qml**

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.12

Entity {
    id: root
    PhongMaterial { id: material; diffuse: Qt.rgba(1.0, 0., 0., 1.0) }


    GeometryRenderer {
                id: geometry


                primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.Triangles


                 geometry: Geometry {
                    boundingVolumePositionAttribute: position

                    Attribute {
                        id: position
                        attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                        vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                        vertexSize: 3
                        count: 2
                        byteOffset: 0
                        byteStride: 3 * 4// 5
                        name: defaultPositionAttributeName
                        buffer: vertexBuffer
                    }


               }

                Buffer {
                    id: vertexBuffer
                    type: Buffer.VertexBuffer
                    data: new Float32Array([
                      -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
                       2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
                       2.0,  2.0, -2.0,

                       -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
                        2.0,  2.0, -2.0,
                        2.0, -2.0, -2.0,

                    ])
                }
            }

    components: [geometry, material ]
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the count variable is the number of vertices in total not the number of triangles.

Answer (score 1):

The `count` variable in the `Attribute` needs to be set to the number of vertices you provide in the vertexBuffer.

```
Attribute {
  id: position
  attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
  vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
  vertexSize: 3
  count: 6
  byteOffset: 0
  byteStride: 3 * 4// 5
  name: defaultPositionAttributeName
  buffer: vertexBuffer
}
```

Another possibility is to avoid duplication of vertices and provide an indexBuffer instead.
The relevant parts then would look like this:

```
geometry: Geometry {
  boundingVolumePositionAttribute: position
  Attribute {
    attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
    vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
    vertexSize: 3
    count: 3
    byteOffset: 0
    byteStride: 3 * 4 // 1 vertex (=3 coordinates) * sizeof(float)
    name: defaultPositionAttributeName
    buffer: vertexBuffer
  }
  Attribute {
    attributeType: Attribute.IndexAttribute
    vertexBaseType: Attribute.UnsignedInt
    vertexSize: 1
    count: 6
    byteOffset: 0
    byteStride: 1 * 4 // 1 index * sizeof(Uint32)
    buffer: indexBuffer
  }
}
Buffer {
  id: vertexBuffer
  type: Buffer.VertexBuffer
  data: new Float32Array([
    -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
    2.0, -2.0, -2.0,
    2.0,  2.0, -2.0
  ])
}
Buffer {
  id: indexBuffer
  type: Buffer.IndexBuffer
  data: new Uint32Array([
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 1
  ])
}
```